# Can't execute conditional statement inside jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with conditional statement in my jQuery function. I initially thought it was the id but confirmed in from another question that this is correct. My question is why the statement inside the condition never executes
when I click the item with id= 5 and how can I fix this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      if ($(this).attr("id") == '5') {
        alert("Not working");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#" id="1">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="4">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="5">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="6">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="7">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code, the event function will trigger when you click on "li" element. So when you write $(this), "li" is the target. Not the "a" where you put the ID. That's is why it is not working. Try to use chrildren to get "a" ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` and `$(this)` inside event handler refer to the element on which event has occurred. The click event is binded on `li` element while ID is on the anchor element inside it. So, `$(this).attr('id')` will be `undefined` as there is no ID attribute on `<li>`.
Use

```
$(this).children('a').attr('id')
```

```js
$('li').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($(this).children('a').attr("id") === '5') {
      alert("Working!!!");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#" id="1">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="4">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="5">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="6">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="7">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because LI does not have the id. ID is with the anchor tag.

```
if($(this).find('a').attr("id") == '5') {
                alert("working");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      if ($(this).attr("id") == '5') {
        alert("working");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">Subjects
        <li><a href="#" id="1">200</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">215</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3">221</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="4">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="5">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="6">250</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="7">220</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">201</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">100</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">101</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```